# Stream Analytics jobs "There is no data from input"

Tags: azure, iot, azure-stream-analytics

I'm trying to create a stream pipeline with the azure IoT hub and a Stream Analytics jobs.

For the first part I'm using a python script to send data from a device in the IoThub, then I set up the routing of the hub to a container where the data is saved.

[image]

After a few minutes, this is the content of the container:

[image]

Now, the part that fails is the Stream Analytics jobs, I have set the input of the job to the iothub:

[image]

And the output to a container:

[image]

But when I test the query:

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    streamdataoutput
FROM
    streamdatainput
```

I get this error:

[image]

Either way I started the job:

[image]

But no data is been saved in the output container, since the query does not work

This is the python code I'm using:

```
device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(conn_str)
device_client.connect()


for i in range(1, 180):
    print("sending message #" + str(i))
    msg = Message("test wind speed " + str(i))
    msg.message_id = uuid.uuid4()
    msg.correlation_id = "correlation-1234"
    msg.custom_properties["payload"] ={"temp":1,"speed":1}
    msg.content_encoding = "utf-8"
    msg.content_type = "application/json"
    device_client.send_message(msg)
    time.sleep(3)
```

**EDIT**

At this point I have deleted the routing to the storage blob, I wasn-t able to view the telemetry in the **Azure IoT Explorer** once I deleted the routing that part work again, but I-m still not able to read the data from the Stream Analytics Job.

This is a sample of the data I can see in the Azure IoT Explorer, could it be that the format of the data is worng? Not sure what the **body** means, since I'm not sending that, also the main message: "msg = Message("test wind speed " + str(i))" is not visible there

```
Thu Sep 02 2021 17:12:30 GMT-0400 (Chile Standard Time):
{
  "body": {
    "0": 116,
    "1": 101,
    "2": 109,
    "3": 112,
    "4": 58,
    "5": 32,
    "6": 49,
    "7": 48
  },
  "enqueuedTime": "Thu Sep 02 2021 17:12:30 GMT-0400 (Chile Standard Time)",
  "properties": {
    "payload": "{'temp': 1, 'speed': 1}"
  },
  "systemProperties": {
    "iothub-connection-device-id": "TempSensor",
    "iothub-connection-auth-method": "{\"scope\":\"device\",\"type\":\"sas\",\"issuer\":\"iothub\",\"acceptingIpFilterRule\":null}",
    "iothub-connection-auth-generation-id": "637662038417651333",
    "iothub-enqueuedtime": 1630617150538,
    "iothub-message-source": "Telemetry",
    "x-opt-sequence-number": 1154,
    "x-opt-offset": "550808",
    "x-opt-enqueued-time": 1630617150616
  }
}
```

As mention by  Florian Eiden,

Comment: Hi there, could you share more about your routing configuration at the IoT Hub level? Depending on how it's set up, you may routing all your events to that container, preventing them from reaching the event hub endpoint.

Comment: Also you should create and dedicate a consumer group to ASA (for each consuming application actually)

Comment: @FlorianEiden Hi, I just updated the question regarding the routing. Also, I'm not following what you mean in the second comment.

Comment: Could you try not using the IoT Hub input adapter of ASA, but instead the Event Hub one by providing the built-in endpoint connection string  (IoT Hub > Settings > Built-in endpoints)

Comment: @FlorianEiden I'll look into it